# After #define: Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Tags: c++

I have the following c++ code:

```
#define MATH_FASTCALL(name, fname) \
static int math_ ## name ## _precall (lua_State *L, StkId func, int nresults) { \
  StkId arg1 = func + 1; \
  llvm_arg_tonumber(L, arg1, 1); \
  setnvalue(func, fname(nvalue(arg1))); \
  L->ci--; \
  L->top = func + 1; \
  L->base = L->ci->base; \
  return PCRC; \
fallback: \
  return luaD_precall_c(L, func, nresults); \
}

MATH_FASTCALL(abs, fabs)
```

When I try to compile it in Visual Studio 14 2015 it gives an error at the line with MATH_FASTCALL:

> expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

What could be the problem with this code?

Comment: If you don't have something like R++ that can expand the macro, do the expansion yourself. Then the compiler will tell you exactly which part causes the problem. Then keep that part and simplify it as much as possible, getting rid of the rest until you end up with a [mcve] that can be run on its own. That's when it's appropriate to ask on SO. Even with the extra code and macro, we can't run this to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message makes it sound like the macro is dereferencing a pointer to an incomplete type. Make sure that `lua_State` and the type of `lua_State::ci` are defined (not just declared) before invoking the macro.

Comment: Tuple_cat, thank you for your response, I'm new to cpp. I'm trying to build https://github.com/neopallium/llvm-lua. I found typedef struct lua_State lua_State; in "lua.h" file that is included, what else do I miss here?

Comment: That's a forward declaration of `lua_State`. You need a definition.

Comment: I've found it in another file that was not included for some reason, now it works. Thank you!